# Cannot get the webcam to work in Skype after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: skype, webcam

After upgrading to Windows 10, I got the new Skype Preview. I cannot get the webcam to work with this new version. I have checked all the settings in Skype Preview and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 because there's a known issue with the upgrade process which makes your webcam stop working on Skype Preview.

The fix is as follows:

1. Open the Run window
2. Type `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\1033` and
   click or tap OK
3. Windows 10 will open File Explorer and take you to a
   folder called 1033. Inside, you will see a file called
   StructuredQuerySchema.bin. Delete it.
4. Restart your computer.

This fix is very well documented here, as well as many other tips for fixing issues with Skype: [Fix webcam issues on Skype](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/webcam-issues-skype)